# Why is the downcast_ref method not found for the dyn Any type?

Tags: casting, rust

I am trying to create my own mocking framework and I've bumped into this problem. When I try to downcast my `Any` type, it does not find the `downcast_ref` method:

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct X;
struct Y;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&'static str, Box<Any + Sync>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("x", Box::new(X));
    map.insert("y", Box::new(Y));

    get_x(map);
}

fn get_x(map: HashMap<&'static str, Box<Any + Sync>>) {
    let ref any = map["x"];
    let res = Any::downcast_ref::<X>(any); // Works
    let res = any.downcast_ref::<X>();     // Fails
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cbb9ce9a0467a5af5b28e4c38b1d5602)

```
error[E0599]: no method named `downcast_ref` found for type `&std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Sync + 'static)>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:18:19
   |
18 |     let res = any.downcast_ref::<X>();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I call it using the associated function syntax, it finds the function and works with no problem.

Why can the compiler not find the `downcast_ref()` method from the variable `any` which is a `dyn Any` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because [`Any::downcast_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) is not implemented for `dyn Any + 'static + Sync`, only for:

- `dyn Any + 'static`
- `dyn Any + 'static + Send`
- `dyn Any + 'static + Send + Sync`

Comment: Hum... yet, apparently, `dyn Any  + 'static + Sync` is convertible to `dyn Any + 'static` automatically, since the function-style call works.

Comment: But why is it not implemented for this permutation?

Comment: I guess it was just forgotten and there was no PR yet.

Comment: @PeterHall: I found an interesting discussion [in the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18737) in which Niko introduced the impl for `Any + Send`. There seems to be a limitation in the "subtype" relationship which prevents stripping `Sync` from `Any + Sync` to consider the impl on just `Any`. It seems to be more an implementation limitation than a fundamental type system limitation.